# Open file picker interface programatically on xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, filepicker

Am trying to get my app to display the file picker interface programatically on button click but when i click on that button, my app crashes...
The button has the label "open" and its supposed to filter files and display only files with the extension ".txt",Here is the code of the method that am trying to achieve that with...

```
 private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Program this button to open a file picker interface
            Intent intent = new Intent(BaseContext, FilesDir.Class);
            intent.PutExtra(FilesDir.AbsolutePath, true);
            StartActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
```

I used java code as blueprint to achieve this but it seems there are some huge difference lines between these two approaches of android programming, Your help is greatly appreciated....
Additional code to help the intent filter for text files only is also greatly welcome too

Comment: what exception causes the crash?  What is the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: It throws this exception ```Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: 'Unable to find explicit activity class {com.companyname.java_tutorial/java.io.File}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?'```

Comment: i thought only the activity namespace is needed and this activity's declaration for the notes class already exists  ```[Activity(Label = "Notes", Theme = "@style/Timothy", MainLauncher = false, ParentActivity = typeof(MainActivity), ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with codes below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.SetType("text/plain");
intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select file"), 1);
```

If you have java code, just update them in the question and I can help you to translate them to C#.

Refer: [how-to-open-pdf-or-txt-file-in-default-app-on-xamarin-forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103042/how-to-open-pdf-or-txt-file-in-default-app-on-xamarin-forms)

Comment: How do i access the chosen file text?

Comment: how do i open the selected file and load the text into edit text?

Comment: load the text into edit text? Write the data to that file.

Comment: Yea that has been my intention al alon, open a text file using the file picker and load the content of the selected text into edit text